# How to Download App to Phone from Mac

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I'm developing applications in Android Studio on my Macbook Pro, and I've figured out how to debug on my actual external device, but I don't know how to download the app to the phone itself, so it's there on the go. With Apple and XCode, all you have to do is run the application, and it automatically downloads to the phone, but Android Studio doesn't do that.

How would I go about doing that?

Comment: yep, Android Studio does that too. If you have the device connected with a cable, before running, it will show you a window to select in which device you want to install and run the app. If it doesn't show, the probably you have a problem with your cable or device.

Comment: I figured it out. Just wasn't looking hard at my applications list. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [[docs](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/running-app.html)]:

To set up the device:

1. Connect to a computer.
2. Enable USB debugging on your device. On Android 4.0 and newer, go to Settings > Developer options.

> Note: On Android 4.2 and newer, Developer options is hidden by
>   default. To make it available, go to Settings > About phone and tap
>   Build number seven times. Return to the previous screen to find
>   Developer options.

Click the green arrow that points right "RUN". Choose your device. And voila!

Answer (score 0):

Personally i use a DROPBOX !

1.Get a Dropbox account and install it on your computer

2.Install Dropbox on your Android phone

3.Create a folder within your Dropbox folder for placing your apk file
Open Dropbox on Android and browse to the folder. Click on the apk file and the installation will start

Answer (score 0):

### Here is the complete guide to your question with simple 5 steps

[image]

1. Fist get your android mobile & navigate to place where <kbd>Build Number</kbd>

   - Stock Android: Settings > About phone > Build number
   - Samsung Galaxy S5: Settings > About device > Build number
   - LG G3: Settings > About phone > Software information > Build number
   - HTC One (M8): Settings > About > Software information > More > Build number
2. Then Tap 7 times coninuesly on <kbd>Build Number</kbd> (you will see a count down & finally it will say `You are a Developer now`)
3. Go Back again & You will see a new option called <kbd>Developer Options</kbd> in the list
4. Go inside that & check the check box `USB Debugging` (you can customize other options also)
5. Connect the mobile phone to mac & run the app from Android Studio.

[image: Your phone shows in the device list]

You will get dialog box in the phone & after you accept that, You will be able to debug the app on your mobile.